# Aligning text vertically using vertical align css

Tags: html, css, responsive

What the hell am I doing wrong haha.
I don't want to set the div's height because it should be set to auto depending on the image next to it. Am I using the tag wrong or something?

See my attached code.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
 .hugme{margin:0 auto;max-width:947px;}
 [class*=bit-]{float:left;padding:5px;}
 
 @font-face {
 font-family: 'Market Deco';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 src: local('Market Deco'), url('http://www.adambwhitten.com/obsw/Market_Deco.woff') format('woff');
 }
 
 /* Grids */
 .box{background:#ed1b2e;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:700;text-align:center;padding:10px 0;}
 .box-2{background:#00aabe;}
 .bit-1{width:100%;}
 .bit-2{width:50%;}
 .bit-2-2{width:50%;}
 .bit-3{width:33.33333%;}
 .bit-4{width:25%;}
 .bit-5{width:20%;}
 .bit-6{width:16.66667%;}
 .bit-7{width:14.28571%;}
 .bit-8{width:12.5%;}
 .bit-9{width:11.11111%;}
 .bit-10{width:10%;}
 .bit-11{width:9.09091%;}
 .bit-12{width:8.33333%;}
 .bit-25{width:25%;}
 .bit-40{width:40%;}
 .bit-60{width:60%;}
 .bit-75{width:75%;}
 .bit-35{width:35%;}
 .bit-65{width:65%;}
        
    .holdsmaller{max-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}
 
 /* Buttons / Video Styles */
 .holdbutton1 {
 z-index:899; 
 margin: 10px;  
   }
   .holdbutton2 {
 z-index:899;
    margin: 10px;
   }
   .holdbutton3 {
 z-index:899;
    margin: 10px;
   }
   .button-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .btnFall {
 -webkit-border-radius: 5;
   -moz-border-radius: 5;
   border-radius: 5px;
   color: #ffffff;
 width:200px;
   font-size: 14px;
   background: #772539;
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   text-decoration: none;}

 .btnFall:hover {
   background: #959356;
   text-decoration: none;
     }
    @media  only screen and (max-width: 756px){
    .button-wrapper{flex-direction: column;}
    }
 
 #cf {position:relative; width:100%; margin:0 auto;}

 #cf img {position:absolute; left:0; width:100%; height:auto; -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;}

 #cf img.top:hover{opacity:0;}
 .showmobile{display:none;}
 
 /* Responsive Goodness */
 /* Defaults above are set Desktop resolution or higher */
 
 /* Laptop */
 @media (min-width:50em) and (max-width:68.75em){
 .bit-7,.bit-35,.bit-65{width:100%;}
 .bit-10,.bit-12,.bit-4,.bit-8{width:50%;}
 }
 
 /* Tablet */
 @media (min-width:30em) and (max-width:50em){
 .bit-10,.bit-12,.bit-4,.bit-6,.bit-8{width:50%;}
 .bit-1,.bit-11,.bit-3,.bit-5,.bit-7,.bit-9{width:100%;}
 img.product {margin-top:43px;}
 img.product2 {margin-top:56px;}
 }
 
 /* Mobile */
 @media (max-width:30em){
    .bit-4{width:50%;}
 .bit-1,.bit-10,.bit-11,.bit-12,.bit-2,.bit-3,.bit-5,.bit-6,.bit-7,.bit-8,.bit-9{width:100%;}
 #cf, img.product, img.product2, img.hidemobile, .button-wrapper {display:none;}
 .showmobile {display:block;}
 }
```

```html
<div class="hugme">
    <div class="bit-2">
    <div class="inner" style="vertical-align:middle;">
    <font style="font-family:'Market Deco'; font-size:50px; color:#772539;">BOOT UP</font><br>
    <font style="font-size:18px; color:#000;">Short, tall, over the knee, or with plush touches.<br>This fall, take your pick.</font>
    <div class="btnFall" style="text-align:center;">SHOP NOW ></div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="bit-2">
    <div id="cf">
   <a href="http://www.google.com/">
    <img class="bottom" src="http://i.imgur.com/J3DOMlR.jpg" width="100%"/> <!-- hover -->
   <img class="top" src="http://i.imgur.com/dMmmOz9.jpg" width="100%"/> <!-- static -->
    </a>
 </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

Thanks guys and gals!

Comment: Please format your code. It's incredibly hard to read in its current state.

Comment: Also `<font>` is an obsolete element and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), `vertical-align` is a property used for inline elements. I don't think it would work on a `div`.